# Media query for mobile (smartphones and tablets)

Tags: media-queries, tablet, mobile-phones, mobile-website

I want to make 2 version of my website, one is targeted for desktop (PC and laptop) and the other is targeted for mobile devices (smartphones and tablets). I've googled it and read some articles about media query. So I put this media query in my design (mostly based on this [reference](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)):

```
/* For mobile and smartphones */ 
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/*style*/
}

/* For tablet */ 
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) {
/*style*/ 
}

/* For iPhones */ 
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and
 (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) { 
/*style*/ 
}
```

I've tested it on several devices. It works well on mobile and smartphones (I tried it on several smartphones such as xperia, samsung galaxy mini and nexus 4), but apparently it didn't work on tablets (I tried it on nexus 7 and galaxy tab). When I open the website on tablets it keep showing the desktop version instead of the mobile version. Any idea how does it happen? Thanks :-)

Comment: This is a good article on where [media queries stop and JS client-side detection starts](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/cross-device/).

Answer (score 0):

did you have the:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the header part of the website? This code will disable the zoom effect on tablets and probably yours mediaqueries will work :)

let me know!

Comment: Yes I already put `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />` in the header :-(

Comment: try to change the:  
    "@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) {"  
with  
    "@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {"